# Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE using a postgres DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]I am getting the error "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE" when running the spring boot application in eclipse.
I have search the web but could not find anything helpful. Please see the code below:-

**Application.properties**

```
server.port=9093
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Sunny@310591
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com.ge.punemmf.qualityputaway=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=logs/spring-boot-logging.log
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
endpoints.sensitive=false
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { CenterOfExcellence.class, WorkOrder.class })
public class WarehouseVisibilityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WarehouseVisibilityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**CenterOfExcellence.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CENTEROFEXCELLENCE")
public class CenterOfExcellence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "CENTEROFEXCELLENCE_WORKORDER", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "center_of_excellence_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workorder_id"))
    private Set<WorkOrder> workorders;

}
```

**WorkOrder.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKORDER")
public class WorkOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String workOrder;
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.warehousevisibility</groupId>
    <artifactId>WarehouseVisibility</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WarehouseVisibility</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**ERROR :-**

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: @g00glen00b : Yes i have added please check the pom.xml now.

Comment: "Is your database running" sounds like the beginning of a bad joke..

Comment: yes DB is running

Comment: I tried a new project with your configuration, and I can run the application. Make sure that your application.properties in in the right location.

Comment: @g00glen00b : Please see the screenshot of the file location of my app...Which IDE did u use for ur application...Can you please push the code in Github and share the link?

Comment: The jar for the Postgres driver may be corrupted. Try clearing it from Maven's cache and running your application again.

Answer (score 0):

This message appear when spring can't see application.properties (and of corse no embedded db set)
To verify that: make sure that the port taken is 9093 not default 8080.

Comment: application.properties is in my resource folder. Please check it.

Comment: Can you please try 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' instead of 'spring.database.driverClassName'.

Comment: So, take a look at an example in my github: https://github.com/montassarelbehi/gpr-back